# R Leaflet Map - addPolygon geography labels

Tags: r, leaflet, polygon, layer, label

I am working a an R leaflet Map, this map has census tracts, each with a number associated. Is it possible to have the labels show on the map, either as you scroll in or with the layer control radio buttons.

The labels are already in the shape files:

```
map1<-leaflet()%>%
  addTiles()%>%

addPolygons(data = plotMerge,
          fillColor = ~pal(plotMerge$incomePerCapita),
          color = "#000000", #this is an outline color hoping to
          fillOpacity = 0.8, # add the labels inside this outline
          weight = 0.2,
          popup=popup)%>%
addLegend(pal = pal,
            values  = plotMerge$incomePerCapita,
            position = "bottomright",
            title = "State-wide Income Percentiles",
            labFormat = labelFormat(digits=1))

saveas(map1, "map1.html")
map1
```

Comment: Can you share some data so I can recreate the map?  I know you can create popups in leaflet.

Comment: I can...but it is a HUGE file in all...I will edit it some tonight to make the symptom reproducible without asking anyone to download 1 GB of data and sift through 200+ lines of code. Thank you...

Comment: Yeah that is understandable.  I'd like to try and help as its been some time since I worked with leaflet, though I enjoyed it when I did.

Comment: The github version of leaflet has that option. You can simply pass a character vector to the `label = ` argument in `addPolygons`.

Comment: Thanks Tim! If you need points for a teddy bear in the stacks shooting gallery feel free to make this an answer...I will give you a check mark and another upvote!

Comment: Nice offer @bethanyP but I am not in for the fame :-)

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the `highlight` option in `addPolygons` like this:

```
leaflet(df) %>% addTiles() %>%
addPolygons(data=df,weight=.85,
    highlight = highlightOptions(
    weight = 5, color= "#666",
    dashArray = "", fillOpacity = 0.7,
    bringToFront = TRUE),
   label=~df$labelyouwant)
```

When you mouse-over the polygon the label will appear.